# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - August 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 23rd edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for August 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                 470
2   nohillside                290
3   bmike                     250
4   ankii                     200
5   Tetsujin                  160
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,719 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-07-01).<sup>1</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                  75
2   bmike                      54
3   ankii                      49
4   nohillside                 48
5   IconDaemon                 42
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                 510
2   PeterJ                    243
3   ankii                     198
4   lhf                       150
5   bmike                     119
```

A big thank you to all 62 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>2</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 49
2   Monomeeth                  20
3   grg                        16
4   bmike                      14
5   fsb                        13
```

A big thank you to all 12 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                 341
2   ankii                     272
3   Nimesh Neema               64
4   fsb                        55
5   Steve Chambers             45
```

A big thank you to all 19 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   ankii                      55
2   Monomeeth                  42
3   fsb                        36
4   Tetsujin                   29
5   bmike, Mark, Nimesh Neema   8
```

A big thank you to all 13 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside, Tetsujin       19
2   Glorfindel                 18
3   Monomeeth                   9
4   Mark                        4
5   grg, Nimesh Neema, Ɱark Ƭ   3
```

A big thank you to all 8 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 18
2   Monomeeth                   8
3   Tetsujin                    5
4   bmike, Glorfindel
    Nimesh Neema                3
```

A big thank you to all 6 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

**NOTE:** This month there was no 5th spot in the scoring.

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 51
2   Glorfindel                 23
3   bmike                      21
4   grg, Monomeeth,
    Nimesh Neema               19
5   fsb                        16
```

A big thank you to all 13 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What does Apple mean by "This may decrease battery life"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366419/what-does-apple-mean-by-this-may-decrease-battery-life)

   - Posted by: someone
   - Votes: **13**
2. [How to stop this icon from appearing on the taskbar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367239/how-to-stop-this-icon-from-appearing-on-the-taskbar)

   - Posted by: c00000fd
   - Votes: **11**
3. [How can I type the name of the person I'm calling on the dial pad and make the call?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365772/how-can-i-type-the-name-of-the-person-im-calling-on-the-dial-pad-and-make-the-c)

   - Posted by: Kevin Barnes
   - Votes: **11**
4. [What does this blue dot in the Dock in Mojave mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365832/what-does-this-blue-dot-in-the-dock-in-mojave-mean)

   - Posted by: tahsmith
   - Votes: **10**
5. [Pipe to mv command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365838/pipe-to-mv-command)

   - Posted by: Vita
   - Votes: **9**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. ['The requested version of macos is not available - macOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366148/168832)

   - Posted by: Nathan
   - Votes: **17**
2. [What does Apple mean by “This may decrease battery life”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366425/168832)

   - Posted by: bmike
   - Votes: **15**
3. [How can I type the name of the person I'm calling on the dial pad and make the call?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/365792/168832)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **14**
4. [How to stop this icon from appearing on the taskbar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367240/168832)

   - Posted by: Joonas
   - Votes: **11**
5. [What does this blue dot in the Dock in Mojave mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/365833/168832)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **11**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. ['The requested version of macos is not available - macOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366141/the-requested-version-of-macos-is-not-available-macos-catalina)

   - Posted by: Nathan
   - Votes: **9,979**
2. [What does Apple mean by "This may decrease battery life"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366419/what-does-apple-mean-by-this-may-decrease-battery-life)

   - Posted by: someone
   - Views: **2,115**
3. [How do I prevent other wifi networks from showing up on my computer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367473/how-do-i-prevent-other-wifi-networks-from-showing-up-on-my-computer)

   - Posted by: spectrum
   - Views: **1,948**
4. ["Install Spotify" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so)

   - Posted by: Insight
   - Votes: **1,773**
5. [What does rm -rf $(!!) mean on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367615/what-does-rm-rf-mean-on-macos)

   - Posted by: mark
   - Votes: **1,746**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [ankii](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/313842/ankii)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside), [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [someone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/320165/someone)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Nathan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/341244/nathan)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Nathan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/341244/nathan)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In August our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **234 flags** with an average handling time of **39 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 375 comments
- deleted 109 posts
- closed 173 posts
- edited 352 posts
- created 134 posts
- created 651 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Due to the possibility of profile changes over time, this link may not reflect the screenshot above.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>